# Evaluate these series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Please help me to evaluate these series. I am working on my physics project and I have encountered to these series. I know that
$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n}}}}{{(2n)!}}}$
is $\cos$ function, but I have problem with $n$. How do i evaluate these series?
$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {n\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n}}}}{{(2n)!}}} $$
and
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n - 1}}}}{{(2n - 1)!}}}$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that for $n\geq 1$,
$$ {n\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n}}}}{{(2n)!}}}=\frac{\alpha}{2} \cdot{\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n-1}}}}{{(2n-1)!}}}\quad
\text{and}\quad {n\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n - 1}}}}{{(2n - 1)!}}}=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2} \cdot{\frac{{{{(\alpha )}^{2n-1}}}}{{(2n - 1)!}}}\right).$$
Now recall the expansions of the main [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\sinh x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{2n - 1} }}
{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}} 
$$
you have that
$$
x\sinh x = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{2n} }}
{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {2n\frac{{x^{2n} }}
{{2n\left( {2n - 1} \right)!}}}  = 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {n\frac{{x^{2n} }}
{{\left( {2n} \right)!}}} 
$$
thus
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {n\frac{{x^{2n} }}
{{\left( {2n} \right)!}}}  = \frac{1}
{2}x\sinh x
$$
By derivation you get the other series